# php json_decode from json file not work

Tags: php, json

I have a file test.json like that:

```
{
    {"code":"ab","name":"Abkhaz","nativeName":"аҧсуа"},
    {"code":"aa","name":"Afar","nativeName":"Afaraf"},
    {"code":"af","name":"Afrikaans","nativeName":"Afrikaans"},
    {"code":"ak","name":"Akan","nativeName":"Akan"},
    {"code":"sq","name":"Albanian","nativeName":"Shqip"},
    {"code":"am","name":"Amharic","nativeName":"አማርኛ"}
}
```

I need to convert in an array in php.

For that I have tried this but **don't work**:

```
$string = file_get_contents("test.json");
$json_array = json_decode($string, true);

print_r($json_array); //return empty
echo count($json_array); //return 0
```

Comment: Your JSON is not validating at jsonlint.com

Comment: You've got an array, not a hash -- the opening `{` and closing `}` should be `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the valid JSON (use http://pro.jsonlint.com/ to check your JSON strings, you need a start and end bracket [] instead of curly braces {}):

```
[
    {
        "code": "ab",
        "name": "Abkhaz",
        "nativeName": "аҧсуа"
    },
    {
        "code": "aa",
        "name": "Afar",
        "nativeName": "Afaraf"
    },
    {
        "code": "af",
        "name": "Afrikaans",
        "nativeName": "Afrikaans"
    },
    {
        "code": "ak",
        "name": "Akan",
        "nativeName": "Akan"
    },
    {
        "code": "sq",
        "name": "Albanian",
        "nativeName": "Shqip"
    },
    {
        "code": "am",
        "name": "Amharic",
        "nativeName": "አማርኛ"
    }
]
```